# How can I see if my password variable is within a line so that my code can proceed?

Tags: python, passwords, user-input

I am creating a password re-setter for school, and i want to check that if the password is within the first line of the text file, then it can say "Okay, choose a new password")

```
Newpass=""
Network=""
setpass=""
Newpass=""
password=""
def newpass():
    Network=open("Userandpass.txt")
    lines=Network.readlines()
    password=input("just to confirm it is you, re-enter your old password:")
    for i in range (3):
        if password in line:
             newpass=input("Okay, choose a new password ")
             Network.close()
             Network=open("Userandpass.txt","a")
             if len(newpass)>= 8 and newpass[0].isalnum()==True and newpass[0].isupper()==True:
                print('password change successful')
                Network.write("New Password  : " + newpass )
                Network.close()
                break
             else:
                print("password did not match requirements, try again ")
        else:
            print("error")
            break
    print("3 tries up or else password updated")

Network=open("Userandpass.txt","w")
Network.write(input("What is your Username")+",")
Network.write(input("Password:")+ ",")
question=input("Do you want to change your password?")
if question=="yes":
    Network.close()
    newpass()
else:
     Network.close()
     print("Okay thank you.")
```

Please help! I have been looking all over here and i can't find a solution

Comment: what is the problem with your current code ?

Comment: anytime i enter when it says enter the old password, if i enter anything like k, it will move on to the next piece of code without checking, even if the password is something like Gateg5ad

Comment: you mean even if you re-enter your old password it prints error and exits ?

Comment: yep, that is what i meant,

Comment: is that only a part of your code? this script is gonna break on `if password in line:` as `line` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: No that is my full code, i wasn't too sure how to resolve it, so i have to define password?

Comment: @sarah Try by changing `lines=Network.readlines()` to `lines=Network.read()`

Comment: @VikasDamodar still the same, it just skipped to choose a new password, even though i didn't enter the right password

Comment: @sarah in your for loop is that `if password in line:` or `if password in lines:` ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar `if password in line`

Comment: @sarah where you have declared the variable `line` ? I cannot see initialization of variable `line` in your code.

Comment: @VikasDamodar when i changed it to lines, it didn't work either.

Comment: @sarah i understood your problem , try this : `if password == lines.split(",")[1]:` instead of `if password in line`

Comment: @VikasDamodar Yes! it worked, thank you

Comment: change if password in line: to if password in lines:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by two things :

```
lines=Network.read() # change here
password=input("just to confirm it is you, re-enter your old password:")
for i in range (3):
    if password == lines.split(",")[1]: # change here also
```

**Explanation :**

The problem with `readlines` is o/p as list where `read` return as string which is better one to use here .
The second thing it returns as a single string ie, combined form of name and password just with `,`. So if you `split` it you will get   an list of separated values. Then you can take only `password` from it and check with input.
In your code you are just checking the `input` element is just present in that whole string, not checking whether it is same password or not

Answer (score 0):

You said you needed this for school, so i assume it's somewhat urgent:

All the changes i did are minor and i commented what i did and why.

```
# no need to intialize these variables
#Newpass=""
#Network=""
#setpass=""
#Newpass=""
#password=""

def newpass():
    # the with open() construct takes care of closing the file for you and gives you a nice handle for working with the file object.
    with open("Userandpass.txt") as Network:
        # this reads all filecontents into a list and while doing so strips away any kind of whitespace.
        username,current_password=[x.strip() for x in Network.readlines()]
    for i in range (3):
        password=input("just to confirm it is you, re-enter your old password: ")
        if password == current_password:
            # communicate the requirements instead of letting potential users run into errors
            newpass=input("Okay, choose a new password (must be 8 chars or more, alphanumeric and have it's first letter capitalized.) ")
            if len(newpass)>= 8 and newpass.isalnum() and newpass[0].isupper():
                with open("Userandpass.txt","a") as Network:
                    print('password change successful')
                    Network.write("New Password  : " + newpass )
                return
            else:
                print("password did not match requirements, try again ")
        else:
            print("error")
            break
    print("3 tries up or else password updated")

with open("Userandpass.txt","w") as pwfile:
    # separate by newline instead of punctuation => personal preference
    pwfile.write(input("What is your Username? ")+"\n")
    pwfile.write(input("Password: ")+ "\n")

question=input("Do you want to change your password? (yes/no): ")

if question[0].lower() == 'y':
    newpass()
else:
    print("Okay thank you.")
    # properly terminate
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you!, this also fixed the for loop issue i had

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an 's' in the line

```
if password in line**s**:
```

maybe the problem comes from there.